# Installing python package failing with "unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory"

Tags: centos, mysql-python

Trying to install mysql-python. Got following error. Got mysql and pythond already installed. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
[root@uu include]# easy_install mysql-python
Searching for mysql-python
Reading http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/mysql-python/
Couldn't find index page for 'mysql-python' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/
Reading http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.3c1
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3c1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.tar.gz#md5=310dd856e439d070b59ece6dd7a0734d
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.tar.gz
Running MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-toQ0nx/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/egg-dist-tmp-OeN5eG
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to install gcc (on centos, some variety of dev-tools)

Answer (score 18):

This will install GCC and others often required:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Can also be installed individual i.e `yum install gcc`