# unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, centos

Is there other way to install gcc on centos apart from yum . 
As in my case yum is not supported as it is proprietary.

Possibly to install gcc using wget,curl,rpm ?

My tox test failed with error 
**"unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"**

Error :

```
  Running setup.py install for netifaces: started
    Running setup.py install for netifaces: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/QKuryr/rootfs/opt/kuryr-libnetwork/.tox/genconfig/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/QKuryr/rootfs/opt/kuryr-libnetwork/pip-install-qukyvv5u/netifaces/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/QKuryr/rootfs/opt/kuryr-libnetwork/pip-record-0gq4z4z1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/QKuryr/rootfs/opt/kuryr-libnetwork/.tox/genconfig/include/site/python3.5/netifaces:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    checking for getifaddrs...not found.
    checking for getnameinfo...not found.
    checking for socket IOCTLs...not found.
    checking for optional header files...none found.
    checking whether struct sockaddr has a length field...no.
    checking which sockaddr_xxx structs are defined...none!
    checking for routing socket support...no.
    checking for sysctl(CTL_NET...) support...no.
    checking for netlink support...no.
    building 'netifaces' extension
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.10.6 -I/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Python3/src/include/python3.5m -c netifaces.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/netifaces.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Fix your machine. Don't ask how to work on a broken machine, most people avoid this situation.

Comment: "_As in my case yum is not working_" what do you mean ?

Comment: Questions about gcc specifically are on-topic here, but if *all of `yum`* is broken, you don't have a gcc-specific problem/question, you have a general-purpose system administration problem, and that's out-of-scope here.

Comment: @bruno sorry was misguiding, i mean yum is not supported as per the architecture.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you working on ARM or something?

Comment: yum is free and open-source. Centos only runs on x64 and yum supports that.

Comment: @n.m. I am using NAS machine where they have proprietary version of linux, hence there is no provision of installing package using yum.                                  
 Hope so you got the answer .                                                                              Ex: [/] # yum
-sh: yum: command not found

Comment: You said, I quote, "install gcc on centos". Now it's an unknown proprietary linux on an unknown architecture. Make up your mind. No one knows how to do stuff on an unknown OS running on an unknown architecture.

Comment: gcc comes preinstalled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing python package failing with "unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088548/installing-python-package-failing-with-unable-to-execute-gcc-no-such-file-or-d)