# Unable to execute 'gcc' : No such file or directory when installing apache superset on IBM i 7.3

Tags: python-3.x, websphere, aix, apache-superset

I am trying to install apache superset from scratch and following recommendation to use virtual environment (venv) and then ran command python3 -m pip install apache-superset. Getting the following error:

```
   Complete output from command /home/XXX/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-z7
```

by2m2a/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code
, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-fqli9xso/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /
tmp/pip-build-env-u0f6md7n --compile --install-headers /home/SHAWNW/venv/include/site/python3.6/cffi:
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

```
       No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to                                                         
       the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See                                                           
       the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related                                                          
       to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that                                                         
       tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about                                                       
       -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/                                                       
       Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or                                                          
       the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)
```

Comment: You might want to install gcc.

Comment: Hi Lorinczy, I did a gcc --version and it replied back with version installed

Comment: Make sure to put it on the PATH in the virtaualenv you use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing python package failing with "unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088548/installing-python-package-failing-with-unable-to-execute-gcc-no-such-file-or-d)